# PostgreSQL query to extract JSON Data

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have the json data in  the column codemap  from which the codes (belonging to removed, revised or added need to be extracted) from the different coding parameter categories such as cpt drg, modifiers, secondaryDiagnosis, principalDiagnosis, secondaryProcedure, observationhours , dischargeStatus ,principalprocedure,hcpcs) need to be extracted

Some images of how my input and expected data look like are below:

Below is how my JSON data looks like

```
{
  "cpt": {
    "added": [],
    "correct": [
      {
        "code": "99497",
        "description": "ADVANCE CARE PLANNING FIRST 30 MIN"
      },
      {
        "code": "96160",
        "description": "ADMINISTRATION OF PATIENT-FOCUSED HEALTH RISK ASSESSMENT INSTRUMENT (EG, HEALTH HAZARD APPRAISAL) WITH SCORING AND DOCUMENTATION, PER STANDARDIZED INSTRUMENT"
      }
    ],
    "removed": [],
    "revised": []
  },
  "drg": {
    "correct": [],
    "revised": []
  },
  "poa": {
    "correct": [],
    "revised": []
  },
  "hcpcs": {
    "added": [
      {
        "code": "G0402",
        "description": "INITIAL PREVENTIVE EXAM"
      }
    ],
    "correct": [],
    "removed": [],
    "revised": []
  },
  "modifiers": {
    "added": [
      {
        "code": "25",
        "description": "Significant Separately Identifiable E&M Service by the Same Physician on the Same Day"
      }
    ],
    "correct": [],
    "removed": [],
    "revised": []
  },
  "dischargeStatus": {
    "correct": [],
    "revised": []
  },
  "observationHours": {
    "correct": [],
    "revised": []
  },
  "injectionInfusion": {
    "added": [],
    "correct": [],
    "removed": [],
    "revised": []
  },
  "principalDiagnosis": {
    "correct": [
      {
        "code": "Z0000",
        "description": "ENCNTR FOR GENERAL ADULT MEDICAL EXAM W/O ABNORMAL FINDINGS (ICD-10) "
      }
    ],
    "revised": []
  },
  "principalProcedure": {
    "added": [],
    "correct": [],
    "removed": [],
    "revised": []
  },
  "secondaryDiagnosis": {
    "added": [
      {
        "code": "E1165",
        "description": "TYPE 2 DIABETES MELLITUS WITH HYPERGLYCEMIA (ICD-10) "
      },
      {
        "code": "Z136",
        "description": "ENCOUNTER FOR SCREENING FOR CARDIOVASCULAR DISORDERS (ICD-10) "
      },
      {
        "code": "Z1211",
        "description": "ENCOUNTER FOR SCREENING FOR MALIGNANT NEOPLASM OF COLON (ICD-10) "
      }
    ],
    "correct": [
      {
        "code": "M25512",
        "description": "PAIN IN LEFT SHOULDER (ICD-10) "
      },
      {
        "code": "Z7984",
        "description": "LONG TERM (CURRENT) USE OF ORAL HYPOGLYCEMIC DRUGS (ICD-10) "
      },
      {
        "code": "Z791",
        "description": "LONG TERM (CURRENT) USE OF NON-STEROIDAL NON-INFLAM (NSAID) (ICD-10) "
      },
      {
        "code": "Z0000",
        "description": "ENCNTR FOR GENERAL ADULT MEDICAL EXAM W/O ABNORMAL FINDINGS (ICD-10) "
      },
      {
        "code": "M25512",
        "description": "PAIN IN LEFT SHOULDER (ICD-10) "
      },
      {
        "code": "Z7984",
        "description": "LONG TERM (CURRENT) USE OF ORAL HYPOGLYCEMIC DRUGS (ICD-10) "
      },
      {
        "code": "Z791",
        "description": "LONG TERM (CURRENT) USE OF NON-STEROIDAL NON-INFLAM (NSAID) (ICD-10) "
      },
      {
        "code": "Z1339",
        "description": "ENCNTR SCREEN EXAM FOR OTHER MENTAL HLTH AND BEHAVRL DISORD (ICD-10) "
      }
    ],
    "removed": [],
    "revised": [
      {
        "to": {
          "code": "M25512",
          "description": "PAIN IN LEFT SHOULDER (ICD-10) "
        },
        "from": {
          "code": "Z79899",
          "description": "OTHER LONG TERM (CURRENT) DRUG THERAPY (ICD-10) "
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "secondaryProcedure": {
    "added": [],
    "correct": [],
    "removed": [],
    "revised": []
  },
  "facilityEvaluationManagement": {
    "added": [],
    "correct": [],
    "removed": [],
    "revised": []
  },
  "professionalEvaluationManagement": {
    "added": [],
    "correct": [],
    "removed": [],
    "revised": [
      {
        "to": {
          "code": "99213",
          "description": "OFF/OP VIS, EST PT, 2KEY COMP: EXPAND PROB HX; EXPAN"
        },
        "from": {
          "code": "99396",
          "description": "PERI COMP PREV MED E&M W/HX/EXAM, EST PT;40-64YR"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Also below is what my input and output tables looks like.

108565-input-data-1.jpg 108546-input-data-2.jpg 108547-output.jpg

Input data:

[image: Input data]

Expected output:

[image: Expected output]

My try on the code:

```
SELECT JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(codemap->'secondardiagnosis' ->'added' ->> 'code') 
    AS secondarydiagnosisaddedcodeadded, * 
  FROM qa_score_report
```

I am not getting any output. What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were providing a string (`code`) to an array function. First parse the array `added` and with the result set parse `code`:

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(codemap->'secondaryDiagnosis'->'added')->'code' 
FROM qa_score_report;
```

Aggregating `code`s into a single row

```
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(trim('"' FROM j::text)),',') 
FROM (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(codemap->'secondaryDiagnosis'->'added')->'code'
      FROM qa_score_report) i (j);
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=af569f6888c2735516b43f993e0a181b)

Comment: Hi Jim...Really appreciate your response...But I am getting an error saying that function json_array_elements(jsonb) does not exist

Comment: @user3369545 you're using a jsonb column, not json. Change the function: `SELECT jsonb_array_elements(codemap->'secondaryDiagnosis'->'added')->'code' 
FROM qa_score_report`

Comment: Hi Jim, Yes this works now...But it is not pulling multiple codes separated by commas in cases where multiple codes are present...

Comment: Also in the case of revised there are from and to within code ..so can I do it this way SELECT jsonb_array_elements(codemap->'secondaryDiagnosis'->'added')->'code' ->'from'
FROM qa_score_report;

Comment: @user3369545 can you try this? `SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(j::text),',') FROM 
(SELECT jsonb_array_elements(codemap->'secondaryDiagnosis'->'added')->'code'
FROM qa_score_report) i (j);`

Comment: Hi Jim...This works except for two cases when I try to add the rest of the elements along with this I am getting the error ERROR:  column "i.j" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(j::text),','),* FROM  
(SELECT jsonb_array_elements(qaauditcodemap->'secondaryDiagnosis'->'removed')->'code',*
 FROM qa_score_report
where date(qaed)>='2021-04-01') i (j)

Comment: Also for SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(j::text),',') FROM  (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(codemap->'secondaryDiagnosis'->'revised')->'code' ->'from' FROM qa_score_report) i (j) and SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(j::text),',') FROM  (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(codemap->'secondaryDiagnosis'->'revised')->'code' ->'to' FROM qa_score_report) i (j) the result output is blank  ....Because in revised there are 'from' and 'to' after code

Comment: In this case try this (3rd query): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f394a045da9edc45d067456458d45386

Comment: Hi Jim...This is awesome and really works!.. Just wanted to check this piece of code with you for revised (because for revised there is from and to codes after code and also I dont want to output rows for which SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(j::text),',') is null ..can I use as below for revised and not output null values SELECT 
 (SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(j::text),',') as diagrevised
  FROM (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(q.codemap->'secondaryDiagnosis'->'revised')->'code'->'from') i (j)),
  *  
FROM qa_score_report q
WHERE date(qaed)>='2021-04-01' and diagrevised is not null

Comment: @user3369545 chekck 3rd query for nulls: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5399ecafda409209f9a0992ec27e4274 regarding `revised`, you want to put it also in an array? should from and to be together in a single column?

Comment: Hi Jim, For revised -I want two separate array columns for from and to...

Comment: @user3369545 chek 4th query, this will give you an idea: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8c24cd8969e22d3f8f919fba76e8b224

Comment: Sure Jim, I tried the following code too..But it doesn't return even one row of data..SELECT jsonb_array_elements(codemap->'cpt'->'revised')->'from'->>'code' AS cptrevised_from,
       jsonb_array_elements(codemap->'cpt'->'revised')->'to'->>'code' AS cptrevised_to,
    jsonb_array_elements(codemap->'cpt'->'added')->>'code' AS cptadded,
    jsonb_array_elements(codemap->'cpt'->'removed')->>'code' AS cptremoved,
    jsonb_array_elements(codemap->'hcpcs'->'revised')->'from'->>'code' AS hcpcsrevised_from, *
from qa_audit_report

Comment: @user3369545 you question seems to not reach en end. Please create a fiddle with data samples, the query and the exact expected result based on the sample data. Otherwise I am afraid we'll be playing ping pong like forever

Comment: Sure Jim!.. Really appreciate your help though!..I am going to start a new thread!

Comment: @user3369545 sounds good. happy coding :-)

Comment: Hi Jim...I have provided the fiddle input and output and my tried query in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68159800/postgres-sql-query-to-summarize-errors-data..Can you please help me here..

Comment: @user3369545 hey there. I cannot find the link for the fiddle. Where is it?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e4a933e7c4141edad7c2bd97a09b3455

Comment: Hi John...I have added the input and the output tables...

Comment: @user3369545 your query is invalid. The whole idea with a fiddle is recreate a minimal reproducible example, so that we can test your queries. Please create a fiddle as I did in my answer.